# Ansible Copy Files

Tags: ansible, rsync, synchronize, brace-expansion

I am trying to copy a bunch of files from server **X** (not control machine) to a group of servers, *targets*: **Y1, Y2, ..., Yn** (defined in host file)

```
files:
   '-path
       '- files
            '- file1
            '- file2
            '- dir
                '- file_x
```

My playbook:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
vars:
  src_dir: /path/files
hosts: {{ targets }}
tasks:
  - name: copying files
    command: "rsync -avrcz X:{{ src_dir }}/{{ artifacts }} {{ dest_dir }}"
```

My command line:

```
./playbook.yml -e '{"targets": "targets", "artifacts" : "{file1,file2,dir/file_x}", "dest_dir": "/yserv/dest/path"}'
```

This works and I am able to parallelize pretty decently, but I keep getting:

> [WARNING]: Consider using synchronize module rather than running rsync

Is there a way to achieve this using synchronize module? Ansible doesn't seem to like bash *brace expansion* syntax. Passing file list as an array and using *with_items* is not practical since it makes the whole thing sequential by invoking rsync for every file and hence is very slow (there is a huge list of files to copy)

Comment: Do you need to copy only those files and not the entire directory structure from `files` downward?

Comment: @XiongChiamiov Thanks for responding. Yes that is a very valid question, but I require the destination dir/file hierarchy slightly different. So if the on X I have: _/store/a/b/c/{d,e}/{f11,f12...}_, there are also files at level /store/a/b say x_1,x_2... on destination I want: _/home/xuser/b/{d,e,f1}/{f11,f12,..}_ and _/home/xuser/b/{x_1,x_2..}_. Hence, in the actuality, in the brace expansion, I pass _{x_1, x_2,c/d,c/e}_

Comment: don't use synchronize module for this, it's buggy even for version 2.3, prefer rsync command

Answer (score 1):

Using rsync in you case is faster. The only down-side is that the task will always return `"changed": false` even if rsync did not change anything. [Synchronize module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/synchronize_module.html) confirm that "You still may need to call rsync directly via command or shell depending on your use case." Just ignore the warning.